# Emacs 25 on Windows does not recognize some keybindings

Tags: windows, emacs, key-bindings, emacs25

I ignored Emacs 25 because of this for a while now and used Emacs 24 but now I have to switch...

So here is the problem: I have a different keyboard layout than default (Colemak) and the key combination `C-M-b` (for example) inserts some unicode character (˘). Emacs 24 ignored this and executed `backward-sexp` as I wanted it. In Emacs 25 though the key is taken literally and inserts the character. I did not find a way to overwrite it.

I tried `(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-b") 'backward-sexp)` and `(global-unset-key (kbd "C-M-b"))` but neither had any effect.

If I run `C-h k C-M-b` (the `describe-key` function) it waits for more input, as if `C-M-b` was a prefix to some key.

Using `(global-set-key (kbd "˘") 'backward-sexp)` (which is ugly anyways) does not work properly either, because the ˘ character gets inserted only after hitting that combination twice, then it gets inserted twice, tough (as for all accent marks). This results in the command running twice and only if i press the key combination twice.

EDIT: This issue occures on Windows 10, on my Linux machine with the same keyboard layout it is not an issue.

How can I fix this? It's truely annoying. Thx in advance

Comment: Perhaps Windows is intercepting that key sequence before it gets to Emacs?  Does it have the same effect in other editors?

Comment: Nope, Emacs 24 is working on the same machine, it's just not working on Emacs 25...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out, how to fix this issue. Turns out that my keyboard layout had a so called "dead" key at that very key combination. I do not know why Emacs 24 did'nt struggle with that while Emacs 25 did, but the solution for me was to modify my keyboard layout and make that key non-dead.